# How to determine if vectors span a set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider the following vectors $v_1 = (1,2,-1)$, $v_2 = (3,-1,1)$, and $v_3 = (-3,8,-5)$

a) *determine if they span $\mathbb{R}^3$?*

I tried doing this question but when i put the vectors to a coefficient matrix the determinence I get is $0$. So i know its not a unique solution but it could no solution or infinite solution. My question is can you see if vectors span if the determinant was to be $0$?

and how would i know if the three vectors or linearly dependent or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to determine if a set of vectors is linearly independent, you should write them as the columns of a matrix $A$. The rank of the matrix equals the number of vectors (number of columns of the matrix) iff the set of vectors are linearly independent. In this particular case you can check that  rank $A$ =3 by computing the determinant, but this approach won't work if the number of rows and columns of $A$ are different.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with rank, it is simply the number of leading entries in any row-echelon form of the matrix.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since the determinant is $0$ (I didn't check it), the vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ are linearly dependent. A set of $3$ linearly dependent vectors cannot span a $3$-dimensional vector space, such as $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: How did you come to conclusion that if the determinent is 0 the three vectors will be dependent? I thought that det(0) means the vector will be independent as they share nothing?

Comment: @karthi97 A standard Linear Algebra theorem asserts that, given $n$ vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$, they are linearly independent if and only if the determinant of the matrix whose columns are those vectors is not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

In case the three vectors are **linearly independent** they span the 3-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

To check whether or not the three given vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ are linearly independent you can put them into a Matrix and perform **Gaussian Elimination** method to obtain the **Row Reduced Echelon Form**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form